# Why were Howard Roark and John Galt both from Ohio?

Tags: ayn-rand, atlas-shrugged, the-fountainhead

Why were John Galt and Howard Roark both from Ohio? Was Ayn Rand making a deliberate parallel here, and why Ohio in particular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ayn Rand's husband, Frank O'Connor, was born in Lorrain, Ohio. When in the process of creating great works it sometimes helps to stay grounded through your most solid partner-rock. [Best available summary here.](https://atlassociety.org/commentary/commentary-blog/6101-5-things-to-know-about-frank-o-connor-ayn-rand-s-husband)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please could you [edit] to include some relevant quotes from the page you link to, instead of just posting the link? Links can go dead over time, and we want this site to be an *enduring* repository of knowledge. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think that explicitly mentioning Frank O'Connor probably obviates the need to further summarize the link - now that AynRandAficionado pointed out that her husband was from Ohio, it makes a lot of sense that that would be why she'd make both of the characters from there too.